# Weird spaces between a tags

Tags: html, css

I'm making dropdown menu with HTML/CSS/JS. Entering five  tags and adding "margin-top: 20px" it should make 20px spaces from top, but it makes bigger and smaller spaces - 24px from top, 28px from top, 28px from top...
I can't find the problem in my code. I was deleting margins, paddings on other classes. Any changes were unsuccessful.

HTML:

```
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><div class="cog"></div></button>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
            <div class="dop"></div>
            <a href="#">Text</a>
            <a href="#">Text</a>
            <a href="#">Text</a>
            <a href="#">Text</a>
            <a href="#">Text</a>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="js/js-1_dropdown.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
.dropbtn {
    height: 34px;
    width: 34px;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background: #ebebeb;   
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 140px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    left: -53px;
    top: 48px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: #b7b7b7;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-family: OpenSans-Regular;
    font-size: 12px; 
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    color: #adadad;
}

.show {display:block;}

.cog {
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 9px;
    left: 9px;
    background: url(img/i-3_settings.png);   
}

.dop {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    top: -4px;
    left: 65px;
}

* {
    outline: none;
}
```

Live - https://jsfiddle.net/qc8aempj/

Ričards.

Comment: Using display: inline-block will render line breaks in your code as a nonbreaking space.

Comment: I think this might be a browser issue as well - because the layout looks evenly spaced to me in your fiddle. Is this odd behavior repeatable in all browsers for you?

Comment: Yes, this is for all browsers.